# Limsup, showing that two expressions are equal

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

I am stuck at this problem which I use for something else.

If $\{a_i\}$ is a sequence of number then I want to prove that

$\limsup |a_i|^{1/i}=\limsup|a_{i+k}|^{|1/i}$, where k is a fixed positive integer.

My idea is as follows. Obviously:

$\limsup |a_i|^{1/i}=\limsup|a_{i+k}|^{1/(k+i)}$, it is just a different way to write the same quantity.

Then I tried this trick:

$\limsup|a_{i+k}|^{1/(k+i)}=\limsup(|a_{i+k}|^{(1/i)})^{i/(i+k)}$. So the problem is now reduced to showing:

> That if we have a sequence $\{B_n\}$, then:
>
> $\limsup |B_n|=\limsup|B_n|^{i/(i+k)}$.

And since the exponent goes to 1 it is almost obvious. If I was working with only lims this would not create any problems, but with lim sup I am not sure.

Comment: I'm sure you mean $k$ is a fixed positive integer.

Comment: @Rustyn Yes thanks!, edited!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\limsup x_i$ is the infimum of numbers $M$ such that for every $\epsilon>0$ we have $x_i\le M+\epsilon$ for all large enough $i$. Thus, it suffices to show that the statements

1. for every $\epsilon>0$ we have $|a_i|^{1/i}\le M+\epsilon$ for all large enough $i$
2. for every $\epsilon>0$ we have $|a_i|^{1/(i+k)}\le M+\epsilon$ for all large enough $i$

are equivalent: if $M$ satisfies one, then it satisfies the other too. This becomes more evident if 2 is rewritten as

3. for every $\epsilon>0$ we have $|a_i|^{1/i}\le (M+\epsilon)^{(i+k)/i}$ for all large enough $i$

Informally, the effect of $(i+k)/i$ is drowned out by the fact that we can put $\epsilon/2$ or $2\epsilon$ in these inequalities.

Comment: There is something I am not following here. If your limit is reached, ie $\exists i \limsup a_n = a_i$ then they are different numbers. Take all the $a_i$ equal to 2.

Comment: For a concrete $\epsilon$, the inequalities are not equivalent. But the statements quantified by $\forall \ \epsilon>0$ are indeed equivalent. The epsilon of room clears out the edge cases like the one you mentioned.

Comment: My bad, I had the wrong definition in head.

Comment: Thanks, I just have two questions, it also incorporates when M is zero or infinity? And is this a correct way of showing that they are equal? I assume I have given an M that satisfies 1., I have to show that the M satisfies 3. given $\epsilon$, I choose $\epsilon/2$ and have that for large enough i, the expression is less than $(M+\epsilon/2)$, then for large I it has to be less then $(M+\epsilon)^{(i+k)/i}$, because with increasing i as mush as we want we can get this expression bigger than $(M+\epsilon/2)$.

Comment: When I assume 3 is true for a given M, and is given $\epsilon$ for 1, I choose $\epsilon/2$, then it is less than $(M+\epsilon/2)^{(i+k)/k}$, for increasing i as much as I want I can get this as close to $(M+\epsilon/2)$ as I want, and hence it is also smaller than $(M+\epsilon)$? So I only need $\epsilon/2$?, not $2\epsilon$?

Comment: @user119615 The case of $0$ works same as $M>0$. The case of infinite limit requires a separate consideration, but it's not hard to see that the sequence $|a_i|^{1/i}$ is unbounded iff the sequence $|a_i|^{1/(i+k)}$ is unbounded. Yes, $\epsilon/2$ is enough since you can put it either in 1 or in 3 when proving one of two directions.

Comment: Thank you very much!, this was truly a smart answer! But there i just one small detail that bothers me still. I wanted to prove that $lim sup |a_i|^{1/i}=lim sup|a_{i+k}|^{1/i}$. From what I see you proved that $limsup|a_i|^{1/i}=limsup|a_i|^{1/(i+k)}$. So in order to get what I want I need that: $lim sup|a_{i+k}|^{1/i}=limsup|a_i|^{1/(i+k)}$, but is this obvious?

Comment: @user119615  I was following up on your idea of reducing the problem to $\limsup|a_{i+k}|^{1/(k+i)} = \limsup |a_{i+k}|^{1/i}$. If you let $b_i=a_{i+k}$ here, the problem becomes what's in my answer.

Comment: Yes I reduced it to $lim sup |B_n|=lim sup |B_n|^{i/(k+i)}$. So then you took the i-root of each side? Are you allowed to do that when you have limsup?

Comment: @user119615 If in $\limsup|a_{i+k}|^{1/(k+i)} = \limsup |a_{i+k}|^{1/i}$ you let $b_i=|a_{i+k}|$, the result is $\limsup b_i^{1/(k+i)} = \limsup b_i^{1/i}$, not what you wrote.

Comment: Oh! now I understand!, thank you so much for your answer! You are extremely smart!

Answer (score 2):

As you have noted above, the original problem will follow from this result:

$\underline {Lemma}$  If $a_n\ge0$ for all $n$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}d_n=1$, then $\limsup a_n=\limsup (a_n)^{d_n}$.

$\underline {Proof}$ Let $s=\limsup a_n$ and $t=\limsup (a_n)^{d_n}$, $\;$where possibly $s=\infty$ or $t=\infty$.

Then $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}a_{n_{k}}=s$ for some subsequence $(a_{n_{k}})$ of $(a_n)$,

so $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(a_{n_{k}}\right)^{d_{n_k}}=s$ and therefore $s\le t$.

Since $\big(\left(a_{n}\right)^{d_{n}}\big)^{\frac{1}{d_n}}=a_n$, applying the same argument shows that $t\le s$.

---

(This argument uses that the lim sup is the least upper bound of the subsequential limits, and is itself a subsequential limit.)

Comment: @user119615  Your idea for finishing the solution to this problem works fine; you just needed this lemma.